# When is a float variable not equal to itself

Tags: c++, floating-point

I was asked this questino on a programming test. The question was, I was passed in a float as a parameter, and asked when would the following code be false.

```
bool result  = (floatValue == floatValue);
```

I couldn't think of a valid reason or a situation of when this would be false and still can't. In the end, I answered that there will never be a case when this would be false. Was wondering if anyone can give me some example(s) of when this would be false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/570694/3093378

Comment: //posted from phone. Will edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661635/why-two-float-type-variables-have-different-values

Comment: This can be false at any time, not just for NaNs

Comment: @M.M how comes? Don't RHS and LHS have exactly the same floating point representation?

Comment: @vsoftco one could be in a register with higher precision as a result of previous calculation

Comment: @M.M That's true when comparing two different float values, but in this case I think you're comparing one variable with itself.

Comment: @M.M. not sure I understand. `floatValue` here refers to the *same* lvalue. It's stored only once.

Comment: The compiler could use a copy left in a register from an earlier calculation for one of the operands

Comment: BTW you mean "same object", not "same lvalue". An lvalue is a category of expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

floatValue == NaN

If floatValue is the result of a computation that is Not a Number, like 0/0.

Comment: OH. I was totally forgetting NaN. Does this also apply if floatValue is INF? Or is this just for when floatValue is NaN?

Comment: Only for NaNs.  Infinities compare normally (-infinity < any real number < +infinity; +infinity == +infinity; etc.).